# AspNetCore "runtimes" is an unsupported framework

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am getting the following when trying to import a AspNetCore MVC Site (WebApplication1) from a new DotNetCore class library in order to run some tests.

Can anyone shine some light on how the compiler works and why this `runtimes is not supported error is coming`? Which hopefully will lead to a fix.

Error:

```
NU1008  "runtimes" is an unsupported framework. 
Taskily.Tests   
%src%\Taskily.Tests\project.json    19
```

%src%\Taskily.Tests\project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "WebApplication1": "1.0.0-preview2-003131",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta3-build3402",
    "xunit.runner.console": "2.2.0-beta3-build3402",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0-beta3-build1187"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

%src%\global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

%src%\WebApplication1\project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication1-19b75b8b-b10e-4fea-94e8-17c9f955732e",


  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build",
      "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" ]
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.2-beta1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": [
      "ssl/*"
    ],
    "define": [ "DEBUG" ]
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "ssl"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trying to import a AspNetCore MVC Site (WebApplication1) from a new DotNetCore class library". What command are you executing to get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a test project is considered a console application (even though you never run it directly), you'll need a reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App`:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "type": "platform",
  "version": "1.0.0"
},
```

The "unsupported framework" error is a rather unhelpful way of saying: "I can't figure out what type of project this is!"

For reference, here's a working Xunit test project.json that I've used recently. You shouldn't need references to `xunit.runner.console` or `runner.visualstudio` for it to work with the Test Explorer.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end the issue was trying to reference `WebApplication1`. I think the problem was I renamed this project in VS Solution, but the folder was still `WebApplication1` and it was getting confused for whatever reason. I since closed solution, renamed the folder to same name as project. Reloaded solution and re-added the project. It now seems to work fine. I do wonder where all of this info is saved so I can edit in future or find it easier than a `unsupported runtime error`. Great error message....